# How to get notifications for automatic minor version upgrade in advance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there any way to receive a notification email before an automatic minor version upgrade begins?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-instances-status-check_sched.html

This page says "AWS sends an email to the email address that's associated with your AWS account prior to the scheduled event", but the root user's email address of the AWS account is not mine.

The page also says "AWS also sends an AWS Health event, which you can monitor and manage using Amazon CloudWatch Events", so I tried to create a rule for RDS scheduledChange event. Under this category there are four types (AWS_RDS_AURORA_HARDWARE_MAINTENANCE_SCHEDULED, AWS_RDS_HARDWARE_MAINTENANCE_SCHEDULED, AWS_RDS_MAINTENANCE_SCHEDULED, AWS_RDS_SYSTEM_UPGRADE_SCHEDULED), but I'm not sure if one of these corresponds to automatic minor version upgrade. I couldn't find any document to confirm that. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

For regular maintenance events, like RDS changes, you can configure [notifications for RDS events](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/notification-maintenance-rds-redshift/).

You can see full [list of events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html) here.

There are probably two events of interest:

`RDS-EVENT-0026` which is sent when the DB begins maintenance.

`RDS-EVENT-0155` which is "The DB instance has a DB engine minor version upgrade available"

RDS instances also have a configurable maintenance window, so you can expect maintenance to always occur in that window if there is pending maintenance.